# Got error while Mounting, error massage:"mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format"

Tags: linux, mount

Im trying to do mount to a nfs server as follow - `mount -t nfs 127.0.0.1 /mnt/mountPointToTest` (I know it is local host, it is just for testing) and I got this error message:

> mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format .

Does anyone know how I can fix this error ?
Thank you.

--
edit: after changing  to `mount -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/var/share /mnt/mountPointToTest`
got error :

> mount.nfs: No such device.

my /etc/exports looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the exported remote share. Let's say you have exported `/var/share` as a share, then your `mount` command would be

```
mount -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/var/share /mnt/mountPointToTest
```

Comment: After I did that I got : "mount.nfs: No such device" . Any idea ?

Comment: Not from the information you gave us. Could you post your `/etc/exports` or whatever file you configured the NFS exports? Maybe that will help.

Comment: I added the post with my `/etc/exports` . Thank you very much!

Comment: Got it. You are **exporting** `/mnt/mountPointToTest` that means your `mount` command should look like `mount -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/mnt/mountPointToTest <mount target>`. Replace `<mount target>` with an empty directory on your machine.